# search not equal whith quicksearch JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search about it but i don't find anything like this.

I use quicksearch on my page to search a type of information and this works, but now I like to search like "notEqual" or !(something) and I don't know how to do.

exemple

I like to see !(Jon)

```
<ul id="ulItens">
    <li>Jon</li>
    <li>Jon Snow</li>
    <li>Jon Winchester</li>
    <li>Sammy</li>
    <li>Dean</li>
</ul>
```

so I like to show this:

```
<ul id="ulItens">
    <li>Sammy</li>
    <li>Dean</li>
</ul>
```

some one know how can I do this?

Comment: How to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where will you show it - inside  another `div` ?

Comment: the list is inside a div

Comment: that `div` is not in your code